# Android Studio 1.5.1 + Data Binding: Error messages in the IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I'm struggling with Android's Data Binding in Android Studio. I get two error messages in the IDE and I don't know how to solve these errors: `Cannot resolve symbol 'BR'` and `Cannot resolve symbol @{data.visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}`.

### This is what I did:

- Installed *Android Support Repository (Rev. 25)* with *Android SDK Manager*
- Created a new Project in *Android Studio 1.5.1*:

  - Application name *DataBindingTest* (domain `my.namespace`, package `namespace.my.databindingtest`)
  - For *Phone and Tablet*, min SDK version 9, target SDK version 23
  - Added an *Empty Activity*
- Added `dataBinding { enabled = true }` to the app module's *build.gradle* file (and did gradle sync)
- Added a `Data` class which extends `BaseObservable` and has the properties `text` (String) and `visible` (Boolean)
- Changed `activity_main.xml`: Wrapped in `layout` tag, added `data` section and used `data.text` and `data.visible` properties.
- Added initialization code to `MainActivity` class

### This is the code of the changed files:

**build.gradle** (Module: app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "namespace.my.databindingtest"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

**Data.java** (package `namespace.my.databindingtest`):

```
package namespace.my.databindingtest;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

public class Data extends BaseObservable {
    private String text;
    private boolean visible;

    public Data(String text, boolean visible) {
        this.text = text;
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.text);
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean getVisible() {
        return this.visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.visible);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml** (res/layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="data" type="namespace.my.databindingtest.Data"/>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="namespace.my.databindingtest.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.text}"
            android:visibility="@{data.visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**MainActivity.java** (package `namespace.my.databindingtest`):

```
package namespace.my.databindingtest;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import namespace.my.databindingtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        Data data = new Data("Hello world!", true);
        binding.setData(data);
    }
}
```

### These are the errors in the IDE:

In the `Data.java` file, `BR` is highlighted in red with the hint `Cannot resolve symbol 'BR'`:

[image: Screenshot Data.java]

In the `activity_main.xml` file, `@{data.visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}` is highlighted in red with the hint `Cannot resolve symbol @{data.visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}`:

[image]

### What I tried so far:

- *File* > *Invalidate Caches / Restart...*
- *Build* > *Clean Project*
- Googled, played around with the code...

So how can I solve these errors?

Comment: Ever solve these issues? I'm having the same problem with visibility expression. It's irritating.

Though, BR is working fine for me, try manually importing import namespace.my.databindingtest.BR

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with BR symbol. I "solved" it by just restarting Android Studio :/ 
(I'm a bit new to Android and IntelliJ)
It seems like that something failed when processing the @Bindable that should create the BR symbols...

Answer (score 0):

try to change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. I have also problems to get the data binding ready to run but I think I've read somewhere that RelativeLayout is not supported yet

Comment: Try finding the source and add it to your answer instead of just saying that *I've read somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Android Studio 2.1 Preview 5
Build #AI-143.2730271, built on March 31, 2016
JRE: 1.7.0_80-b15 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

this 3 steps helped me to recover:

1. shutdown Android Studio
2. gradlew clean
3. open Android Studion and Build->"Make Project"

Answer (score 0):

You can do your UI logic in MV(ModelView).I mean Data.java file

```
public class Data extends BaseObservable {
private String text;
private boolean visible;

public Data(String text, boolean visible) {
    this.text = text;
    this.visible = visible;
}

@Bindable
public String getText() {
    return this.text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.text);
}

@Bindable
public boolean getVisible() {
    return this.visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.visible);
}
}
```

In your xml file you can add it like this

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{data.text}"
        android:visibility="@{data.visible}"/>
```

Please dont do your UI logic in view please do it in MV.